# Make a Ruby class comparable to Date class

Tags: ruby, date, rspec, compare

How can I specify a class to be comparable with a Date?

```
class FolderDate

  attr_reader :folder

  def initialize folder
    @folder = folder
  end
end

class AsteriskFolderDate < FolderDate

  include Comparable

  attr_reader :date

  def initialize folder
    super
    @date = get_date
  end

  def <=>(other)
    @date <=> other
  end

  private
    #omitted
end
```

In Rails console...

```
AsteriskFolderDate.new("20130628") > Date.today-1
 => true
AsteriskFolderDate.new("20130627") > Date.today
 => false
```

Spec file...

```
describe "An instance of", AsteriskFolderDate do
  let(:folder) { DateFolder.new(Date.today).asterisk_folder }

  subject { AsteriskFolderDate.new(folder) }

  #omitted

  it "should compare based on @date" do
    expect( Date.today-1 ).to be < subject
    expect( subject ).to be > Date.today-1
  end
end
```

Test fails...

```
Failure/Error: expect( Date.today-1 ).to be < subject
  ArgumentError:
   comparison of Date with AsteriskFolderDate failed
```

The console output makes me want to think it's working, but the test is failing. Am I on the right track, or are the tests pointing out a flaw I'm missing in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order in which you're comparing.  If you do this in the Rails console:

```
Date.today < AsteriskFolderDate.new("20130627")
```

You will see the same error.  Only one of your assertions will throw an error:

```
it "should compare based on @date" do
  expect( Date.today-1 ).to be < subject  # Fails
  expect( subject ).to be > Date.today-1  # Works
end
```

This is because AsteriskFolderDate knows how to compare itself to Date's, but the standard ruby Date object doesn't know anything about AsteriskFolderDate (which is expected).

If you want the comparison to work both ways you'll need to modify the Date class in some way.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified methods in your `AsteriskFolderDate` class make it comparable with `Date`. So  the following just works fine:

```rb
AsteriskFolderDate.new(Date.today.strftime("%Y%m%d")) > Date.today-1
#=> true
AsteriskFolderDate.new((Date.today - 1).strftime("%Y%m%d")) > Date.today
#=> false
```

But you didn't monkey patch `Date` to make it comparable with your custom class `AsteriskFolderDate`. And when you write `Date.today < AsteriskFolderDate.new("20130627")` the `<` message is sent to the instance of `Date`, however, `Date` doesn't know how to compare with `AsteriskFolderDate`, thus an argument error is raised from `Date#<`.

```rb
Date.today-1 < AsteriskFolderDate.new(Date.today.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
# folder_date.rb:23:in `<': comparison of Date with FolderDate failed (ArgumentError)
#        from folder_date.rb:23:in `<main>'
```